# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'. ERROR

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[TabloGetir] (@id  INT,
                                   @ay  INT,
                                   @yil INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
      (SELECT ARACKM_ARAC_ID,
              ARACKM_ID,
              ARACKM_TARIHI,
              ARACKM_KM,
              A_PLAKA,
              A_ID
       FROM   VARACKM
       WHERE  A_ID = @id
              AND MONTH(ARACKM_TARIHI) = @ay
              AND YEAR(ARACKM_TARIHI) = @yil)
```

This is my tabled-valued function and i keep getting that error can someone please help me?

This is where i call it:

```cs
comm2 = New SqlCommand(@"select ARACKM_TARIHI, SUM(ARACKM_KM) AS TUTAR 
                         from VARACKM 
                         GROUP BY ARACKM_TARIHI 
                         HAVING [dbo].[TabloGetir](@A_ID,@ay,@yil) ",conn2)

comm2.Parameters.Add("@A_ID", plakaId)  
comm2.Parameters.Add("@ay", ay)
comm2.Parameters.Add("@yil", yil)
reader2 = comm2.ExecuteReader()
```

Comment: Are you getting this error when you define the function or when you call it?

Comment: i am getting this error when i call it

Comment: So please show the code that calls it.

Comment: comm2 = New SqlCommand("select ARACKM_TARIHI, SUM(ARACKM_KM) AS TUTAR from VARACKM GROUP BY ARACKM_TARIHI HAVING [dbo].[TabloGetir](@A_ID,@ay,@yil) ",conn2)

Comment: What are you trying to do with `HAVING [dbo].[TabloGetir](@A_ID,@ay,@yil)`? It doesn't reference any columns from the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `having` clause.

```
HAVING [dbo].[TabloGetir](@A_ID,@ay,@yil)
```

First, your function is returning a table, and the `having` clause expects a scalar with some sort of comparison.  Second, you have no comparison.  Perhaps you mean:

```
HAVING EXISTS (select 1 from [dbo].[TabloGetir](@A_ID,@ay,@yil) )
```